# How do I get a row value to filter a selector column in the same row? (row by row as well)

Tags: acumatica

I created a selector that displays files belonging to customers. I placed this selector in the Stock Items Cross-Reference table. The goal of this selector is to display all files associated with the customer of that row within the Cross-Reference table.

[image]

The code for my selector DAC field is as follows:

```
using PX.SM;

[PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Specification")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<UploadFileRevision.comment, 
  InnerJoin<UploadFile, On<UploadFile.fileID, Equal<UploadFileRevision.fileID>>,
  InnerJoin<NoteDoc, On<NoteDoc.fileID, Equal<UploadFile.fileID>>,
  InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.noteID, Equal<NoteDoc.noteID>>,
  InnerJoin<INItemXRef, On<INItemXRef.bAccountID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>>,
  InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INItemXRef.inventoryID>>
>>>>>, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>

//, And<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>

>, Aggregate<GroupBy<UploadFileRevision.comment>>>),
typeof(UploadFileRevision.comment), typeof(UploadFile.name), 
typeof(UploadFile.fileID))]
```

This filters all of the files correctly belonging to all customers associated to the item through the cross reference table, but it does not filter each selector per line within the table. If I uncomment the commented line, adding logic to filter by current BAccountID, the selector results return nothing.

Is there any other way to grab a value from a row and use that in a selector belonging to that row in a table to filter its results?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to add another conidtion to your where statement and point to the current initemxref record (not sure of the key there). But i think you are just missing your Current<> entry to point to the currently selected xref row. Maybe by alternate ID?

Comment: Would the equal be And<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<INItemXRef.bAccountID>>>  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will composing the Where clause for BAccount.bAccountID as `...And<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<INItemXRef.bAccountID>>...` result in the proper behavior?

Comment: Thanks Ruslan and Brendan. That suggestion did what I needed. I don't know how I overlooked that obvious relationship.